# Laravel get file extension in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When I want to show a docx icon if a user has uploaded a docx file I receive the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getClientOriginalExtension() (View: /home/vagrant/Code/support/local/resources/views/users/ticket.blade.php)
```

I'm trying it like this:

```
@foreach($ticket->image as $photo)
     @if($photo->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'docx') 
           <img src="icons/word.png">
      @else
<a href="{{ $photo->path }}"><img src="{{ $photo->path }}" alt=""/></a>
       @endif
 @endforeach
```

Obviously the `getClientOriginalExtension()` is not right. But what should I use instead?

Answer (score 6):

You should use:

```
@if (pathinfo($photo->path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'docx')
```

instead of:

```
@if($photo->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'docx')
```